# iniciar threads juntas python3

Tags: python-3.x

Como iniciar as threads juntas ?

**Contexto** :
Tenho uma classe que extende a classe Threading.Thread.
Porém, quando vou iniciar as threads, me parece que elas estão sendo executadas sequencialmente.

Exemplo : 
1. Entra no for; 
2. Instancia-se a primeira thread; 
3. Executa o método "run", através do método "start";
4. Espera a execução terminar - **toda ela**;
5. Entra na próxima iteração do for;
6. Volta para o passo 1.

```
from threading import Thread
class Thread_test(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def run(self):
        ''' ALGUMA COISA PARA EXECUTAR'''


for i in range(10):
    thread = Thread_test()
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
```

Comment: É exatamente isso que está acontecendo - e exatamente isso que deveria acontecer. Você sabe o que o método [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) faz?

Comment: Mais ou menos ! Eu queria que em dado ponto as threads aguardassem o término de todas as outras threads para continuar o resto do script...